# Generación de Informes lanza excepciones aleatoriamente

Tags: c#, excepciones, ssrs

Esta es la situación. Tengo una aplicación de consola en `C#` que se usa para generar ciertos informes. A esta aplicación de consola se la llama desde una aplicación hecha en `VB6` (Esto no creo que sea relevante, pero lo comento por aportar toda la información) con unos parámetros que se usan para generar el informe. Esta combinación de aplicaciones `VB6` y aplicación de consola `C#` está instalada en varios equipos en la red local.

El problema es que, en algunas ocasiones, el informe no se genera y lanza esta excepción:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. In System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item) In Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.MemoryReportSnapshot.CreateReportChunk(String name, ReportChunkTypes type, String mimeType)...

Y en otras ocasiones,este error menos descriptivo todavía:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing...

La cuestión es que esto no pasa todo el tiempo, y no siempre en los mismo equipos, parece ser totalmente aleatorio.De hecho, si justo después de recibir la excepción vuelves a intentarlo con exactamente los mimos parámetros, normalmente se genera correctamente el informe.

He estado investigando bastante, y encontré [esto](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eebc842b-fc20-498e-99d8-42e554cd5ad0/indexoutofrangeexception-thrown-from-reportviewer-control-when-processing-a-report?forum=vsreportcontrols) por ejemplo. Ahi se sugiere que el problema tiene que ver con problemas de multihilo, y que añadiendo una ordenación explícita en todos las regiones de datos debería solucionar el problema. He intentado hacer esto, pero no he solucionado nada.

También existe  [este hotfix de Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/961282/fix-error-message-when-you-try-to-display-a-report-in-sql-server-2008) que parece estar relacionado con mi problema, pero habla de la version 2008 de Sql Server. Otros también informan de que actualizando la versión de las `dll's` de los `Reporting Services` se soluciona el problema. Ahora mismo cambié las versiones y estoy usando la `12.0.2402.20` de `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll`,`Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll` y `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll`, pero el problema continúa ahi. A ver si alguien puede darme alguna idea sobre el tema :)

Answer (score 1):

Ver tu código sería de ayuda, pero por lo que deduzco, el problema es que el elemento item que intentas añadir al list por el método add, no existe. Entonces la solución es comprobar primero que exista antes de añadirlo a la lista, aunque el problema no está solucionado, lo estará cuando encuentres el porqué de que haya veces que el elemento item no exista.